# SSIS Expression - get the next characters

Tags: regex, ssis, expression, flat-file

I need to get the exact file name of a txt file as the connection string of my flat file connection manager. I have used the following expression:

```
@[User::DataLoadDir]+"Myfile_" +  (DT_STR, 4, 1252) YEAR (getdate()) + RIGHT ("0" + LTRIM ((DT_STR, 4, 1252) MONTH (getdate())), 2) + RIGHT ("0" + LTRIM ((DT_STR, 4, 1252) DAY (getdate())), 2) + ".TXT"
```

That returns

```
C:\Mypath\Myfile_20131203.TXT
```

But actually my filename has additionaldigits after the dates. 
It is

```
C:\Mypath\Myfile_20131203034537.TXT
```

What change should I do on my current expression? Is there something like putting * to indicate that it should accept any characters?

Comment: How can we know what the digits are? Do you know that the file is `MyFile_034537.TXT` and you need to push the date after the underscore?

Comment: You could use a wildcard in a Foreach Loop container, maybe? ([simple example here](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm).)

Comment: You are not using your filename in expression at all...